# Time Series Prediction using multiple variables

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis

My Dataset looks like

[image]

Question: How can i predict 2018 weeks 13 to 18 using data of 2018 weeks 1 to 12 for Max temp, Min temp, Rain, Humidity, Wind Speed.

Should I predict first Min temp, Rain, Humi, Wind Spd using each variables own history. 
OR
I should use multivariate time series and predict all variables

Comment: Of course you want to use all the available information if possible so a multivariate time series, however this may be hard.